# Set meta robots to noindex for /directory/currency/switch/currency/

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, meta-tags

How can I set meta robots to noindex for pages like www.mysite.com/directory/currency/switch/currency/USD/...?

I have many urls of this kind indexed and I want to remove them.

Comment: [Cross-post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/190282/5949)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the layout XML. You would just need to find the correct handler for the page.

```
<your_handler_here>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="setRobots"><value>noindex</value></action>
   </reference>
</your_handler_here>
```

However, those type of URLs should redirect which would make it so they don't get indexed.

The simplest solution would be to just add `Disallow: /directory/currency/switch/currency/` to your robots.txt file so that it's disallowed.

If that doesn't work then you can also apply the [X-Robots-Tag](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag) header. In Apache this would be something like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "^directory/currency/switch">
        Header set X-Robots-Tag: "noindex"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

You can read more about how to implement the custom header [here](https://yoast.com/x-robots-tag-play/).

Comment: The problem is to finf the correct handler. I've just added the line above to robots.txt file.

Comment: @GiovanniPutignano There's not going to be a handler for the page since it redirects. I've updated the answer to include a method which uses apache to set an `X-Robots-Tag` header instead which will do the same thing.